# Create a view with a validation (TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a view in T-SQL. It should show some kind of "conflicts".

**The problem**

I do not know how to create a smart statement with the appropriate logic.

**First explanation try**

I have a table of values as sequences. I want to check if the sequence is serial (0, 1, 2, etc...). If it is serial, everything is ok.

The view should only show entries with a **non-serial** sequence (0, 1, 3, 5, 8, etc.).

The database could look like this:

[image: Persons and Meals]

**Simplifying the problem:**

Imagine a person. If this person eats dinner **BEFORE** lunch, there is a conflict. Basically all I want to do is to show all conflicts in this view, and the people who did not obey the sequence.

I am happy for any help.

---

**EDIT**

The Sequence attribute contains the order of the meals.

Comment: You need to rephrase the question then you can even google for the answer - you want to find gaps in a sequence. All else just confuses the issue

Comment: Use subquery: `... WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id-1 FROM ..)`

Comment: Check [The TSQL of Gaps and Islands in a Sequence](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the meals for each person using `row_number()`.  I think the following might do what you want:

```
select *
from (select mp.*, row_number() over (partition by personid order by timeofday) as seqnum
      from mealperson mp
     ) mp join
     meal m
     on mp.mealid = m.mealid
where seqnum <> m.sequence;
```

EDIT:

If you are looking for gaps in a strict enumeration:

```
select mp.*
from (select *, lag(m.sequence) over (partition by personid order by m.sequence) as prev_sequence
      from mealperson mp join
           meal m
           on mp.mealid = m.mealid
     ) mp
where prev_sequence is not null and prev_sequence <> sequence - 1;
```

Comment: I am using the Sequence Attribute in the Meal table to enumerate the meals. I will however look into that code.

Comment: I think this could work, but I forgot to mention that I am using MSSQL 2005. Maybe I could upgrade to 2008, if there is a better way there. LAG is a function implemented up from MSSQL 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I interpret this is what you need?

## Sub query:

for id's: 1, 2, 4

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE id NOT IN (Select id-1 FROM table)
```

shows all id's with no preceding number: 1 and 4

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE id IN (Select id-1 FROM table)
```

shows all id's with preceding number: 2

## join

```
SELECT t2.id 
FROM table t1
LEFT join table t2
ON t1.id=(t2.id-1)
```

If t2 is null then their is no preceding id.
so use: WHERE `t2.[column] = null`